# PHP Classes for Fractal Generation?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, image-manipulation, fractals

I'm just curious (this is after HEAVY searching) if there are any classes for 
PHP and GD/ImageMagick for generating Fractal images under different algorithms
like Gumowski-Mira, Fractal Flame, etcetra. It would save me a ridiculous amount
of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nat McHugh has posted a few PHP scripts for fractals on [github](https://github.com/natmchugh/PHP-Fractals) following a talk he gave on the subject at the Sheffield PHP group

Comment: @ehime - Just spoken with Nat - he says feel free to offer suggestions on github

Comment: I'll talk to him, I ended up writing a generator in JS instead =( I still want a nice hefty library that will do Fractal Flames though